# Repeated calls to format ignore the ~t option

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this:

```
(defun promptread (prompt) 
  (format *query-io* "~10t~a:" prompt)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))
(defun prompt-cd ()
    (make-cd
     (promptread "Artist")
     (promptread "Album")
     (promptread "Rating")
     (promptread "Like [y/n]")))
```

It works, however the format `~10t` only affects the first call to `promptread` inside `make-cd`; the others are left-aligned without this padding.

Why would this be?

REPL:

```
CL-USER> (addcds)
          Artist:Dixie
 Album:Funny
 Rating:22
```

The first `promptread` is indented because of the `format` with `~10t` but not the others, which use the same exact `format` call.

Comment: Can you give complete code, the results, plus what you expect? We can't really verify what's going on, since we don't have any of this.

Comment: Looks like Terje D. has answered your question, but it's best to try to post all the code that someone would need to reproduce your error. I can't run `addcds`, because you haven't provided the code for it. You have your answer now, so we don't really need the code, but to make future questions easier, make it possible for us to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that after `force-output` and `readline`, the cursor is not known to `format`to be at position 0. Thus absolute tabulation will fail.  If you start the format string with `~&`, you will see this as an additional newline will be outputted anyway.

To solve the problem use the `@` modifier to get relative tabulation:

```
(format *query-io* "~10@t~a:" prompt)
```